# what does $\operatorname{diag}(0,0,\ldots,0, 1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read a paper, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8283591 and it said that $D_m$ is a $MN_T$ by $MN_T$ matrix,and

$D_m=\operatorname{diag}(0,0,\ldots,0, 1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$,first we have $(m-1)N_T $ zeros,then $N_T$ ones,and the last are $(M-m)N_T$ zeros

Can anyone tell me what does $\operatorname{diag}(0,0,\ldots,0, 1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ look like when $M=3,N_T=4,m=1,2,\ldots,M$? I mean can anyone show me something like matrix form below,i think the $D_m$ is an identity matrix,but I am not sure about that

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: $\operatorname{diag}$ means a **diagonal** matrix, with the given numbers appearing in the diagonal in the given order (from top-left to bottom-right). E.g. $$\operatorname{diag}(1,-3,2) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Diag(0,0,0,0\dots 0,1,1\dots1,0\dots,0)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 & 0 & ...&0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 & ...& 0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 &...& 0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
&\vdots & &&&\vdots &&&& \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 & 0 & ...&0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 1 &0 & ...&0 & ... & 0 &0&0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &1 & ...&0 & ... & 0 &0&0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &0 & ...&1 & ... & 0 &0&0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 & 0 & ...&0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
&\vdots & &&&\vdots &&&& \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 & 0 & ...&0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 & ...& 0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 &...& 0 & ... &0 & 0 & 0 &\\
\end{bmatrix}$

And in Block Matrix form it is simply $\begin{bmatrix}O& O &O\\O&I_m&O\\O&O&O\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$

$I_m=m\times m$ Identity matrix. Hope this works.

Comment: how do we know the number of zeros?because we have $(m-1)N_T$ zeros,but m=1,2,3

Comment: I am not sure of that. Could you please provide a link to the paper you have read? It will help me and others about the definitions of the notations like $N_T$.

Comment: OK i have edited the problem